# How to extend WP_query to a specific table?

Tags: wp-query, database, search, customization

I created a new table (named extrapage) in the wordpress database (named wpsite_db). I have added to this table some pages not published directly with wordpress and I want these pages to be considered when searching the site. But I don't know how to proceed. I did some research and learned that I would have to extend WP_query to my new table. But I'm a novice and I don't know how to proceed in real life.

Can someone help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this table an exact copy of wp_posts? Why are you using a custom table to begin with? How are you adding content to this table.

Comment: Hello @Jacob, In fact I created the wordpress site in a php site subfolder (I wanted the blog part to be wordpress). And so, when you search on the blog, the pages of the php site are naturally not considered. I have duplicated the wp_posts table and filled in manually to extend the search to this table.

Comment: Have you considered using custom post types?

Comment: @TomJNowell How can I use post types if I want to include posts that are not published with wordpress?

Comment: you would use custom post types instead of them, since we don't know anything about this other system, how it works, or how it stores its data it's super difficult to give advice, but, you can't just plumb new tables into `WP_Query`

Comment: You may want to instead look into a totally separate search engine that can index content from the main site as well as WordPress. No, you won't be able to use WP_Query for data outside of standard posts. You could, in theory, build your own search engine that searches both WP posts and your other site, but that would be pretty complicated. Probably easier to look into a search engine that can crawl all of the content for you, and be embedded in the WP site (and also in the main site, if you choose).

Comment: @TomJNowell the php site is static. It's just pages that I had developed in html and transformed into php.

Comment: Thank you @WebElaine for your comment. I also think that the most obvious solution would be yours. Then I'll think about it.